# Redis Server Error - Connection to Redis localhost:6379 failed after 1 failures.Last Error : (1) Connection refused

Tags: php, redis, centos

I have a peculiar situation,  The Redis Server is running and am getting the PONG reply from the Redis Server,  but I get the following Error

I tried to reinstall the Server and also restarted the Server but getting the Same issue

Please help to resolve

```
    *** Starting worker xxxxxxxxx.plesk.page:1078:SMS_RESPONSE
    ======================================================================
       The applicHation has thrown an exception!
    ======================================================================
     Resque_RedisException
     Error communicating with Redis: Connection to Redis localhost:6379 failed after 1 failures.Last Error : (1) Connection refused
     ----------------------------------------------------------------------
    /resque/php-resque/lib/Resque/Redis.php:152
    #0 /resque/php-resque/lib/Resque.php(69): Resque_Redis->__construct()
    #1 /resque/php-resque/lib/Resque/Worker.php(104): Resque::redis()
    #2 /resque/php-resque/lib/Resque/Worker.php(517): Resque_Worker::all()
    #3 /resque/php-resque/lib/Resque/Worker.php(391): Resque_Worker->pruneDeadWorkers()
    #4 /resque/php-resque/lib/Resque/Worker.php(167): Resque_Worker->startup()
    #5 httpdocs/module/Admin/src/Controller/SmssController.php(359): Resque_Worker->work()
    #6 /laminas/laminas-mvc/src/Controller/AbstractActionController.php(71): 
 ""
```